# Parity transformation on annihilation operator for the Dirac field $U(p)^{+} c_{r}(\vec k)U(p)=i c_{r}(- \vec k)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry

I want to verify the discrete parity transformation action on annihilation operator for the Dirac field.

Given the dirac field:
$$
\psi(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \int \frac{d^3k}{\sqrt{2\omega_k}} \sum_{r=1}^{2} \left[ c_r(k) u_r(k)e^{-ikx} + d^\dagger_r(k) v_r(k)e^{+ikx}\right]
$$
and the annihilation operator: 
$$
c_{r}(k)= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \int \frac{d^3x}{\sqrt{2\omega_k}}(u^{+}_r(k)\psi(x)e^{ikx})
$$

$$\boxed{U(p)^{+} \psi (\vec x,t )U(p)=i\gamma_{0}\psi (-\vec x,t )}$$
$$\boxed{U(p)^{+} c_{r}(\vec k)U(p)=i c_{r}(- \vec k)}$$

My attempt: 
$$U(p)^{+} c_{r}(\vec k)U(p) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \int \frac{d^3x}{\sqrt{2\omega_k}} u^{+}_r(k) U^{+}(k)\psi(\vec x,t)U(k)e^{E_kt-kx}= $$
$$=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \int \frac{d^3x}{\sqrt{2\omega_k}} u^{+}_r(k) i \gamma_0 \psi(-\vec x,t)e^{E_kt-kx}$$
If we take 
$$x=-x \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,k=-k$$

$$U(p)^{+} c_{r}(\vec k)U(p) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \int \frac{d^3x}{\sqrt{2\omega_k}} u^{+}_r(-k)i\gamma_0 \psi(\vec x,t)e^{E_kt-kx} $$
I really don't know what to do with the $ \gamma_ {0} $.